# How to search the DOM for an item with certain class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm brand new to JavaScript. I want to know if it's possible to search an HTML page for an element with a known class.

If this is possible how do i do this?

I've got this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("top_prodname");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. What does this mean -> "ts possible to search a HTML page with a certain URL" What is the definition of an item here?  Might be beneficial to add an example

Comment: Take a look at [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: theres an HTML page which contains the following tag   ```<span class="top_prodname">example</span><br/>```, i want to find it trough javascript

Comment: So what did you try and what was the result ? Your single-line javascript looks ok

Comment: my problem is that i dont know how to specify the url that i want javascript to search

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail than that? Maybe provide some example inputs and desired outputs? I'm not tracking what you mean when you talk about searching a URL.

Comment: When i say URL i mean a Website, like an actual website that you go to when browsing, in that website there´s information that i want to store in variable, and in the source code of that website, i can see that information is in <span class="top_prodname">example</span>, i want to acess that webpage trough URL in javascript and store this information

Comment: Are you asking how to access the contents of another web page from your web page?  If so, you could use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the content from the URL and then use DOM methods to find the desired element.

Comment: Just to clarify, a URL is a string that serves as an address to a resource like a web page. You're wanting to search the markup (AKA, the DOM) of a web page. URLs are not relevant to your programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean about the URL. You can use `document.querySelector()` to find DOM elements. Here's an example:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".top_prodname");

console.log(x);
```

```html
<span class="top_prodname">example</span>
```

As @0stone0 commented, you can learn more about `querySelector` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Using `getElementsByClassName()` should work fine, too. You can't create more specific selectors with `getElementsByClassName()` like you can with `querySelector()`. Although, if getting element references by class name is really all you need, this is fine. Note that it returns an array of element references.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("top_prodname");

console.log(x[0]);
```

```html
<span class="top_prodname">example</span>
```